# in gobject's spawn_async, why doesn't my child process appear to see data until its stdin pipe is full

Tags: asynchronous, pipe, pygtk, glib, gobject

I use the following calls to spawn a process, get back file descriptors for its stdin, stdout, and stderr, and watch for output on its stdout:

```
[widget.pid,widget.stdin,widget.stdout,widget.stderr] = \
        gobject.spawn_async(['/bin/sed','s/hi/by/g'], 
                            standard_input=True,
                            standard_output=True,
                            standard_error=True
                            )
gobject.io_add_watch(widget.stdout,
                  gobject.IO_IN,
                  getdata)
```

I then write lines to widget.stdin, expecting to trigger the callback function getdata.

What I find is that my getdata callback only gets called once the pipe to widget.stdin has been filled, rather than as soon as I send my first newline.  The complete test program is here, along with its output.   I don't get any calls back to getdata until the pipe fills or until I close the pipe, then I finally get sed's returned data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# example base.py
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import gobject
import os
import time
import fcntl

F_SETPIPE_SZ = 1031  # Linux 2.6.35+
F_GETPIPE_SZ = 1032  # Linux 2.6.35+

def data_can_be_sent(source,cb_condition):
    msg = "hi there how are you\n"
    try:
        print "Source, cond, send", source, cb_condition, msg
        #print "Also sending padding x's and a newline to make 512 bytes."
        os.write(source, msg)
        os.write(source,"\n")
        os.write(source,"-"*(510-len(msg)))
        os.write(source,"\n")
        time.sleep(0.1)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        print "Could not print in data_can_be_sent"
    return True

def getdata(source,cb_condition):
    try:
        p = os.read(source,4096)
        print "Source, cond, get", Base.pipesize, source, cb_condition, "[", p, "]"
    except:
        print "Could not print in getdata."
    return True

class Base:
    pipesize = 0

    def hello(self, widget, data=None):
        print "Hello"
        print gobject
        try:
            print "fstat",os.fstat(widget.stdin)
            print "fsync"
            os.fsync(widget.stdin)
        except AttributeError as e:
            print "Attribute Error",e
            print "Spawning sed process"
            [widget.pid,widget.stdin,widget.stdout,widget.stderr] = \
                gobject.spawn_async(['/bin/sed','s/hi/by/g'], 
                                    standard_input=True,
                                    standard_output=True,
                                    standard_error=True
                                    )
            print widget.pid,widget.stdin,widget.stdout,widget.stderr
            print "Pipe size",fcntl.fcntl(widget.stdin,F_GETPIPE_SZ)
            print "SET Pipe size",fcntl.fcntl(widget.stdin,F_SETPIPE_SZ,10)
            Base.pipesize = fcntl.fcntl(widget.stdin,F_GETPIPE_SZ)
            print "Pipe size",fcntl.fcntl(widget.stdin,F_GETPIPE_SZ)
            gobject.io_add_watch(widget.stdin,
                                 gobject.IO_OUT,
                                 data_can_be_sent)
            gobject.io_add_watch(widget.stdout,
                                 gobject.IO_IN | gobject.IO_PRI,
                                 getdata)
            os.write(widget.stdin, "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n"*64)
            os.write(widget.stdin, "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n"*64)
            os.write(widget.stdin, "ccccccccccccccc\n"*64)
            os.write(widget.stdin, "ddddddddddddddd\n"*64)

        except OSError as e:
            print "NONATTRIB",e.errno
            print "NONATTRIB",e.strerror

    def delete_event(self, width, event, data=None):
        print "delete event, returning False so window is destroyed"
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        print "destroy received"
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)
        # Here we connect the "destroy" event to a signal handler.
        # This event occurs when we call gtk_widget_destroy() on the window,
        # or if we return FALSE in the "delete_event" callback.
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)

        self.button = gtk.Button("Hello World")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.hello, None)
        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.button.show()
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

The output looks like this:

```
$ python pytest.py
__main__
Hello
<module 'gobject' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/__init__.pyc'>
fstat Attribute Error 'gtk.Button' object has no attribute 'stdin'
Spawning sed process
29594 16 17 19
Pipe size 65536
SET Pipe size 4096
Pipe size 4096
Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, get 4096 17 1 [ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
(more a's, b's, c's, and d's)...
ddddddddddddddd
]
Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, get 4096 17 1 [ by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
]
Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

delete event, returning False so window is destroyed
destroy received
Source, cond, send 16 4 hi there how are you

Source, cond, get 4096 17 1 [ by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
by there how are you

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
]
```

Update: In response to drahnr's comment below, I tried this using gtk in C, with the call

```
ret = g_spawn_async_with_pipes(".", /* working directory */
             spawn_argv, /* gchar **argv,*/
             NULL, /* gchar **envp,*/
             0L, /* GSpawnFlags flags,*/
             NULL, /* GSpawnChildSetupFunc child_setup,*/
             NULL, /* gpointer user_data,*/
             &pid, /*GPid *child_pid,*/
             &spawn_stdin, /* gint *standard_input,*/
             &spawn_stdout, /* gint *standard_output, */
             &spawn_stderr, /* gint *standard_error, */
             NULL /*GError **error*/
             );
```

and got the same results; no return from sed until after at least 4096 bytes had been sent to sed, even though there was a newline every ten chars.

Comment: I've tried reducing the size of the read from 4096 to 512 has no effect, I still need to push 4096 bytes before I get to read any.  I've also tried reregistering the write callback each time and having it return False in hopes of offering the read callback priority over the write callback; no change.

Comment: Did you try a minimal example in C? Or the introspection of gtk/glib _without_ the pygtk wrapper?

Comment: I haven't yet.  I haven't used gtk/glib from anything but Python.  It doesn't seem at all obvious that the Python pipes should have a different behavior than the C pipes, since I believe both use the same system calls.

Comment: It is not about the system calls (which are identical indeed), but about the wrapper potentially doing some harm. That is why I suggested either to test with glib in C or the _generated_ introspection instead of the pygtk wrapper (that stuff with `from gi.repository import GObject ...`).

Comment: Using (http://blog.borovsak.si/2009/07/spawning-processes-using-glib.html) as a starting point, I tried using g_spawn_async_with_pipes directly from a C/GTK application.  I found that sending "hi there" plus a newline 400 times and flushing the channel did not trigger the input callback, but sending "hi there" plus a newline 410 times DID trigger the input callback.  So the same problematic behavior with respect to output to the child process is evident in g_spawn_async_with_pipes, at least when the flags argument is set to 0L.

Comment: (Note that each time I sent "hi there\n" I specified a write size of 10, not 9.  Changing the string to "hi there!\n" so that the tenth character wasn't an overflow byte made no difference.  It seems you need to fill the pipe to the child with 4096 (presumably) chars to get it to flush to the child.

Comment: Did you try to add a `fflush` after the `fprintf` statements?

Comment: `   g_print("Writing chars\n");
    for( x=0; x<10; x++)
      {
        g_io_channel_write( channel, "hi there!\n", 10, &size );
        g_print("Wrote %d chars\n",size);
      }
    g_print("Wrote chars, now flushing channel\n");
    g_io_channel_flush( channel, NULL);
    g_print("Flushed channel\n");`

Comment: File a bug, I think this is one - http://bugzilla.gnome.org